# Android Get indication if the user chooses to install an offered app

Tags: android

Suppose my app has a WebView that offers the user to install another app (Which is not necessarily my own) like so:

**WebView HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title> Get this app </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ori.memo.friend"> Install app! :) </a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Is there a way my app could get an indication if the user has chosen to install this app from the market? I mean knowing for certain that the user has actually installed the app? I'm thinking to implement this with a hybrid web app but of course I am open to other suggestions if they are better for this use case.

Comment: do you want to only know if he choosed to click or if it's fully installed ?

Comment: I want to know if it's fully installed.

Answer (score 1):

I'll explain it the Hybrid way :

If you know the Package Name of the app to install you can check if it is installed in the Android system and then put a Flag on send a request to your BackEnd

this can be done this way :

```
isAppInstalled("com.example.com");

private boolean isAppInstalled(String packageName) {
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    boolean installed = false;
    try {
       pm.getPackageInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
       installed = true;
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
       installed = false;
    }
    return installed;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This way I have to take care of the edge case that a user might have already installed this app in the past. Is there another way?

Comment: not really only if you want to take care of that case